# CGI echoes POST data - security issue?

Tags: javascript, security, cgi

I'd like to generate a file on a website using JavaScript and provide it for download by the user. I learned that this is not possible using plain JavaScript and HTML5.

I'm thinking of posting the generated file contents to a CGI function on my server that just echoes the data. By setting the right headers I could provide the data for download this way.

I'm wondering if such an echo CGI function could be misused and result in security problems. The website (also the CGI function) is password protected using basic authentication.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [indeed possible to do this using `data:` URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3665147/413180):

```html
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,//5mAG8AbwAgAGIAYQByAAoA">text file</a>
```

However, if you still wish to use the CGI method, there are security risks of allowing a page to echo POSTed data. This is known as [reflected Cross Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Say you have a CGI listening on `https://example.com/cgi-bin/downloader`.

Assume the user is already authenticated with your basic authentication and then receives an email containing a link. The user visits the website in the email (say `evil.com`) which creates a POST request submitted by JavaScript to `https://example.com/cgi-bin/downloader` containing a HTML document which also contains some JavaScript to send the cookies from your domain to the attacker. Even if you are setting the correct `content-type` header to identify the HTTP response as XML, [some browsers (IE) will try to sniff the content](http://labs.detectify.com/private/109881869381/tumblr_nj5i3t5b101tqlxa5) and present the Content Type that the browser thinks it is to the user (HTML in this case). To avoid this, make sure that the following header is set in the response:

```
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

So using this header in combination with a Content Type of `text/xml` in the response should mitigate the risk of XSS. I also recommend the [Content-Disposition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) header being set so the file will be downloaded rather than displayed:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="bar.xml"
```

To prevent other sites making requests to your CGI service in the first place, you could use a [CSRF prevention](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) method. The recommended method is the "Synchronizer Token Pattern" and this involves creating a server side token that is tied to user session that must be submitted with the POST request. Whether this is possible with your system using basic authentication is for you to decide. The `Referer` header can be used, although this is less secure:

> checking the referer is considered to be a weaker form of CSRF protection. For example, open redirect vulnerabilities can be used to exploit GET-based requests that are protected with a referer check and some organizations or browser tools remove referrer headers as a form of data protection. There are also common implementation mistakes with referer checks. For example if the CSRF attack originates from an HTTPS domain then the referer will be omitted. In this case the lack of a referer should be considered to be an attack when the request is performing a state change. Also note that the attacker has limited influence over the referer. For example, if the victim's domain is "site.com" then an attacker have the CSRF exploit originate from "site.com.attacker.com" which may fool a broken referer check implementation. XSS can be used to bypass a referer check.
>
> In short, referer checking is a reasonable form of CSRF intrusion detection and prevention even though it is not a complete protection. Referer checking can detect some attacks but not stop all attacks. For example, if you HTTP referrer is from a different domain and you are expecting requests from your domain only, you can safely block that request.

You should also test this to make sure that [script will not be executed when an XML is downloaded using Internet Explorer](http://webstersprodigy.net/2012/02/04/serving-back-xml-for-xss/).

Comment: That was the kind of evil stuff I thought about.

Comment: I'd love to use data URLs, but they seem to be very limited. Currently I want to provide an XML file and it seems like IE is unable to load them from data URLs.

Comment: If HTML files are the only potential risk, the CGI function could disallow this MIME type. Maybe it could also check the referrer.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, I thought you meant generate a JavaScript file, not XML. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all it does is echo data coming from the client, I don't see any security issues. That data was already known to the client. You are just changing headers so the browser will allow you to save the contents as a file.

You are not disclosing any information to parties that don't already have access.